# .htaccess - Redirect parent to subfolder but keep original URL and path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would need some help regarding an .htaccess problem. I am a beginner with apache configuration and i'm trying to do this :

Given this file tree :

```
/myhost.com
├───services/
│   ├───doc/
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   ├───locales
│   │   ├───vendor
│   │   └───index.html
│   ├───service1/
│   ├───service2/
│   └───service3/
```

- I am trying to redirect the **myhost.com/services** route to myhost.com/services/doc/(index.html) by keeping the original URL
- I would also like to continue to access (service1/2/3) by the real URL (*myhost.com/services/service(1|2|3)*)

My current .htaccess is this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myhost\.com[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/services/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /services/doc/ [R]
```

As you can see I use the *R* flag which makes everything works but its not keeping the original URL */services/*

By not using the *R* flag the URL doesn't change, the good page is loaded *BUT* the resources needed by the html for example a script : **(src="vendor/require.min.js")** which paths are relative are not found :

In console:
GET https://www.myhost.com/services/vendor/require.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Is there a way to make this work ?

**PS**: Of course I would like to not edit my index.html because its auto-generated

Comment: Where is the vendor/ folder?

Comment: In the doc folder (I forgot to write it in the tree)

Comment: Fixed my problem with a base tag in the html